# Live drawing of a line in D3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js, jquery-svg, svg-animate

I'm just started with D3.js, and I want to create something like what we do in Paint to draw a line. The steps are should be the same:
- Click on a point on the screen
- Drag to the destination to create a line.

What I'm having troubles now is when you drag your mouse to the destination, the line should move according to your mouse. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you put an example of your code onto http://jsbin.com/ or jsfiddle so we could see what it's currently doing?

Comment: Without code it's hard to see exactly what you are looking for but [this code](https://gist.github.com/benzguo/4370043) pretty much does the dragging (with other functions which you may not need, but worth a look)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a simple example. Also see [live version](http://jsfiddle.net/9tr7w/360/).

```
var line;

var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 600)
    .attr("height", 400)
    .on("mousedown", mousedown)
    .on("mouseup", mouseup);

function mousedown() {
    var m = d3.mouse(this);
    line = vis.append("line")
        .attr("x1", m[0])
        .attr("y1", m[1])
        .attr("x2", m[0])
        .attr("y2", m[1]);

    vis.on("mousemove", mousemove);
}

function mousemove() {
    var m = d3.mouse(this);
    line.attr("x2", m[0])
        .attr("y2", m[1]);
}

function mouseup() {
    vis.on("mousemove", null);
}
```

I think the part you're looking for is in the `mousemove` event handler where we select the current line and adjust it's destination point based on the current mouse location. Note that we only enable `mousemove` in `mousedown` to avoid superfluous processing.