# Can i draw line on mouse click position in d3.js after graph is generated completely?

Tags: d3.js

Is it feasible to draw a line on scatter plot graph once graph is completely plotted. I should click or drag my x-axis so that line will follow with my mouse, if leave mouse click it should  plot a simple straight line,so that i can figure out the scatter plots in better comparison.

is it possible to make a straight line on d3.js completed graph.just by clicking where we want?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273884/live-drawing-of-a-line-in-d3-js